# pacman -Syu error with npm ( conflicting files )

Tags: linux, arch-linux, npm, pacman

I just tried to run pacman -Syu command and encountered this error:

```
(417/417) sprawdzanie kluczy w bazie                                                                                   [########################################################################] 100%
(417/417) sprawdzanie spójności pakietów                                                                               [########################################################################] 100%
(417/417) wczytywanie listy plików                                                                                     [########################################################################] 100%
(417/417) sprawdzanie konfliktów plików                                                                                [########################################################################] 100%
błąd:  nie udało się dokonać transakcji (konfliktujące pliki)
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cmd-shim/lib/to-batch-syntax.js znajduje się w systemie plików
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/gentle-fs/lib/chown.js znajduje się w systemie plików
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/gentle-fs/lib/mkdir.js znajduje się w systemie plików
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-cmd-shim/LICENSE znajduje się w systemie plików
Wystąpiły błędy, nie zaktualizowano żadnego pakietu.
```

Which you can translate as following:

```
(417/417) checking the keys in the database [######################################## ################################] 100%
(417/417) checking package integrity [######################################### ###############################] 100%
(417/417) loading file list [######################################### ###############################] 100%
(417/417) checking file conflicts [######################################### ###############################] 100%
error: transaction failed (conflicting files)
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cmd-shim/lib/to-batch-syntax.js is in the file system
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/gentle-fs/lib/chown.js is in the file system
npm: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/gentle-fs/lib/mkdir.js is in the file system
npm: / usr / lib / node_modules / npm / node_modules / read-cmd-shim / LICENSE is in the file system
There were errors, no package has been updated.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Log as root, delete the listed files and rerun.

That happened because you probably ran npm directly to update itself (probably)... Which you should avoid ...([Here is an example of why - but it's a personal opinion](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19883)).

You may consider [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) as mentioned in the [Alternate installations method of the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Node.js#Alternate_installations)...